# Finding a formula for the sum $\frac{n}{1}+....+\frac{n}{logn}$

Tags: inequality

I have the equation below.
I want to find an answer:

When $n\rightarrow \infty $

$$\frac{n}{1}+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{3}+\frac{n}{4}+....+\frac{n}{logn}=?$$

$$n * [\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+....+\frac{1}{logn}]=?$$

I am raising the equation, but I want something closer ...

$$n * [\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+....\frac{1}{logn}] \leq nlogn$$

Comment: Since $\log n$ is never an integer when $n$ is an integer, do you mean $$\frac{n}{1}+\dots+\frac{n}{\lfloor \log n\rfloor}$$?

Comment: The la would be more simply $\frac 11+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1L\le L$

Comment: Alsok th elimit as $n\to\infty$ is certainly $\infty$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean? $n\rightarrow \infty $

Comment: Can you show the expression for, say, n=2?

Comment: i don't understand your series. It looks like you have a series like this:$n\times \left( \frac1{log10}+\frac1{log100}+\frac1{log1000}...\right)$ and hence $n$ should be an integral multiple of 10... and further the series is in H.P. so we don;t have a formula for the sum of that.... (up to my knowledge)

Comment: What do you mean by $n \to +\infty$?  The entire expression approaches $+\infty$ as $n \to +\infty$, becuause $n$ grows (significantly) more quickly than $\log n$.

Comment: you should provide more information

Comment: Technically, this isn't a series, it is a sequence.

Comment: Well, the whole thing is $\geq n$ so as $n\to\infty$ it approaches infinity. In my answer, I give a decent approximation for what the value is for a particular $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $H_k=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{k}=\log k + \gamma + \epsilon_k$ where $\epsilon_k\sim \frac{1}{2k}$, you get:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor}\frac{n}{m} = n\log\lfloor\log n\rfloor + \gamma n + \iota_{n}$$

where $\iota_n \sim \frac{n}{\lfloor \log n\rfloor}\sim \frac{n}{2\log n}$. So, $\iota_n$ does not approach zero.

You actually have that $n\log \lfloor \log n\rfloor = n\log\log n + O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$, so we get:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor}\frac{n}{m} = n\log\log n + \gamma n + O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$$

In all of the above, $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant.